# How to map list of objects

Tags: reactjs

I am consuming an endpoint that returns a JSON object of this format, I am a bit confused about how to map this.

```
 const data = [
        [
          [
            {value:'123'},
            {value:'124553'},
            {value:'1253'},
          ]
        ]
    ]
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Please post your desired output.

Comment: You will have to add more details. Is the array containing only one element. If not do you want to render this using JSX or only use in JS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some ways to achieve this goal. Here are some examples:

#### Deconstructing the map/matrix

```js
const [ [ values ] ] = data;
values.map(({ value }) => ...)
```

#### Direct access

```js
data[0][0]?.map(({ value }) => ...);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can something like

```
data.map(item=> {
  return item.map((item1) => {
    item1.map(value=>{
      console.log(value.value); // gives 123 ,124553 ,1253
    })
  })
})
```